# Magento: Remove Product Special Price 'From' & 'To' Date Requirement

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I'm trying to remove the 'From' & 'To' Date requirement from the Special Price function but can't find the correct file. I'm not sure if it's in the core php files or the template phtmls.

The Magento store I use is integrated with a Point of Sales System which imports the products including the 'special price' field and this is updated every 5 minutes but no dates can be passed through from the POS system so I need to remove the from and to date part of the price calculation.

Edit:
So far I've found these files which call 'getSpecialToDate()'
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Collection.php
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Price.php
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php

But I still haven't been able to modify them to get the desired result.

I've tried changing the files to include hard coded dates instead of calling the dates. For example in Collection.php line around 1079 from

```
$specialPriceFrom = $product->getSpecialFromDate();
$specialPriceTo = $product->getSpecialToDate();
```

to:

```
$specialPriceFrom = '1990-01-01 00:00:00';
$specialPriceTo = '2099-12-31 00:00:00';
```

Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

In magento 'special_from_date' and 'special_to_date' is attributes.
So you can mange it from admin panel.

Go to admin->catalog->attributes->Manage attribute sets.
Here select your attribute set to edit it.
Here if you Drag and drop `special_from_date` and `special_to_date` to unassigned attributes than not move because of system attributes.

Go to mageto Database and find `eav_attribute` table.
Find rows which `attribute_code` is `special_from_date` and `special_to_date`.
In that row find column `is_user_defined` change that value 0 to 1.
Now in admin panel move that attributes to unassigned attributes.
Save that attribute set.
Now "Special Price From Date" and "Special Price To Date" removed in saved attribute set.